# How to resolve ERROR: epmd error for host nxdomain (non-existing domain)?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I am trying to setup RabbitMQ Operator and RabbitMQ Cluster  on K8S cluster on bare metal using this [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/using-operator.html#create)

K8S Cluster has got 1 master and 1 worker node

RabbitMQ Cluster pod log

[root@re-ctrl01 containers]# kubectl logs definition-server-0 -n rabbitmq-system

```
BOOT FAILED  (Tailored output)
===========
ERROR: epmd error for host definition-server-0.definition-nodes.rabbitmq-system: nxdomain (non-existing domain)

11:51:13.733 [error] Supervisor rabbit_prelaunch_sup had child prelaunch started with rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase() at undefined exit with reason {epmd_error,"definition-server-0.definition-nodes.rabbitmq-system",nxdomain} in context start_error.  Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...
```

[root@re-ctrl01 containers]# kubectl describe pod definition-server-0 -n rabbitmq-system

```
Name:         definition-server-0
Namespace:    rabbitmq-system
Priority:     0
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  44s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned rabbitmq-system/definition-server-0 to re-ctrl01.local
  Normal   Pulled     43s               kubelet            Container image "rabbitmq:3.8.16-management" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    43s               kubelet            Created container setup-container
  Normal   Started    43s               kubelet            Started container setup-container
  Normal   Pulled     42s               kubelet            Container image "rabbitmq:3.8.16-management" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    42s               kubelet            Created container rabbitmq
  Normal   Started    42s               kubelet            Started container rabbitmq
  Warning  Unhealthy  4s (x3 over 24s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: dial tcp 10.244.0.xxx:5672: connect: connection refused
```

I added the following entries to `/etc/hosts` file of `worker node` because I am NOT sure whether the entry has to be added to `master or worker`

```
[root@re-worker01 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
127.0.0.1   re-worker01.local re-worker01 definition-server-0.definition-nodes.rabbitmq-system
```

I am stuck with this issue for almost 2 days.  I googled and found similar issues but none resolved my issue

I see multiple issues in pod logs and describe output and I am unable to find out the root cause

1. Where can I find `erl_crash.dump`  file on K8S ?
2. Is this really a hostname related issue ?
3. 10.244.0.xxx:5672: connect: connection refused  - Is this issue is because of `'epmd'` or something else ?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to resolve the issue after spending lot of time

I added the host `definition-server-0.definition-nodes.rabbitmq-system` to `/etc/hosts` file of RabbitMQ Cluster pod using **hostAliases**

YAML to add **hostAliases** is given below

```
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
  name: definition
  namespace: rabbitmq-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  override:
    statefulSet:
      spec:
        template:
          spec:
            containers: []
            hostAliases:
            - ip: "127.0.0.1"
              hostnames:
              - "definition-server-0"
              - "definition-server-0.definition-nodes.rabbitmq-system"
```