# Rabbit MQ changing hostname while preserving rabbitMQ artifacts and messages

Tags: linux, rabbitmq

This question is regarding rabbitmq config
I hope this question is appropriate for stackoverflow forum.
Please point me to right forum if it isnt

My problem statement that I need to to change hostname of a linux server from "thishost" to "thathost"
The host "thishost" has RabbitMQ installed on it with a ton of artifacts and messages
I need to be able to preserve all the RabbitMQ artifacts such as queues, exchanges and also messages when the hostname changes to "thathost"

I am considering configuration change to enable rabbitmq  see old hostname (thishost) despite the name change for linux

To ensure that rabbitmq hostname remains same I peg it to the original hostname by configuring following two parameters in the rabbitmq configuration file

```
/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
...
HOSTNAME=thishost
NODENAME=rabbit@thishost
```

Having done this change in rabbitmq config,  I changed the linux hostname to "thathost" and try to start the rabbitmq service.

The rabbitmq service now refuses to start and the error messages are as follows

```
service rabbitmq-server start
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

journalctl -xe
Nov 30 11:20:07 ubuntula1 systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ Messaging Server.
Nov 30 11:20:18 ubuntula1 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The logfile /var/log/rabbitq shows following error

```
/var/log/rabbitq 
 ERROR: epmd error for host thishost: nxdomain (non-existing domain)
```

Any thoughts on

- how to fix the rabbitmq config
- any alternative way on making rabbitmq agnostic to hostname
- is there  a better idea to preserve the rabbitmq artifacts across hostnames

Please note I tried following

1. export import artifacts using rabbitmqctl  export__definitions/import_definitions
2. Store and load messages using rabbitio
   However as I mentioned I have a ton of artifacts and messages and the rigor involved  that approach makes it error prone so I am searching for a less rigorous approach

Thanks much folks

Comment: I stumbled upon this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68179365/how-to-resolve-error-epmd-error-for-host-nxdomain-non-existing-domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the error message in logfile "epmd error for host thishost: nxdomain (non-existing domain)"
I stumbled upon this post  [How to resolve ERROR: epmd error for host nxdomain (non-existing domain)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68179365/how-to-resolve-error-epmd-error-for-host-nxdomain-non-existing-domain)
While this is not directly relevant, it sure provides a tip that a /etc/hosts entry is needed for mapping old hostname to the same ip address.

With alias for old hostname addded in /etc/hosts my problem was solved :-)

SO to sum it up, if you want to change the hostname of your linux host - then you need to do two things to save your artifacts from becoming unusable after hostname change

1. Change to rabbitmq configuration as I already described
   /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
   ...
   HOSTNAME=thishost
2. Make an alisas in my /etc/hosts to add old hostname mapping to ip address in addition to new hostname as follows

   /etc/hosts
   ...
   a.b.c.d thathost thishost

That solved my problem and rabbitmq starts fine with all existing artifacts intact after hostname change